# Rating scale 1-10

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have survey data with rating survey responses "Excellent", "Very Good"."Good" or Poor. How do I replace these texts in excel with number range - "9-10", "7-8" or "0-6"

Comment: Look into CHOOSE() or a database with VLOOKUP

Answer (score 2):

`=CHOOSE(MATCH(A1,{"Excellent","Very Good","Good","Poor"},0),"9-10","7-8","5-6","0-4")`

*I made up the numbers, since your question showed 4 options and 3 results only.*

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with a simple `=IF()` construction, something like:

```
=IF(OR(A1=9,A1=10),"Excellent",
    IF(OR(A1=7,A1=8),...),
    ...
   )
```